# Create Bingmap pushpins from shape name

Tags: javascript, gis, bing-maps

I need to create pushpins for the below input.

```
var Countries = ["Austria", "Brazil", "India", "Germany", "USA", "Malaysia"];

Microsoft.Maps.SpatialDataService.GeoDataAPIManager.getBoundary(Countries, geoDataRequestOptions, map,
        (data) => {
            var value = data.location;
            if (data.results.length > 0 && data.results[0].Polygons !== null) {
                var polygons = data.results[0].Polygons;
                var dataBounds = Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromShapes(data.results[0].Polygons);
                var loc = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(dataBounds.center.latitude, dataBounds.center.longitude);
                var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(loc, {
                        icon: svgIcon,
                        anchor: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(20 / 2, 20 / 2) 
                });
                map.entities.push(pin);
                locs.push(pin);
                map.setView({ bounds: Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromLocations(locs), padding: 80 });  
            }
        });
}, 3000);
```

I am using GeoDataAPIManager to get the boundary polygons and get the center of the polygon to generate a pushpin. But when loading countries like Malaysia or USA, the pushpins are placed in the sea, as the `getboundary()` returns multiple polygons and getting the center of the polygon returns the center between the two boundaries which results in the pushpin placed in the sea.

Let me know if there is any alternate way to create the pushpin or to get the center of the polygon.

I already tried the `spatial.Math` module to get the center.

Comment: To clarify, you want the pushpins to always be on land? I'm not familiar with the Bing Maps API, but is there a way to search for geometries and not include the (small) islands? Maybe filter out the biggest polygon and select that for placing the pushpin.

Comment: Sounds like you want something similar to this: https://github.com/mapbox/polylabel

Answer (score 0):

This is a common occurrence when working with polygons as their shape can be such that their center is not within the actually geometry. There are several different ways to do this.

Method 1: This method will fall back to the nearest point to the calculated center that's on the edge of the polygon.

- Calculate centroid/center either using math library or rough center by using bounding box center.
- Check to see if the point intersects the polygon, if not, calculate the closest point on the edge of the polygon (shortest distance), then use that point as your center.

Method 2: Focus just on the largest polygon.

- If the geometry is a MultiPolygon, calculate the area and grab the polygon with the largest area. For the USA, this would give you the polygon for the mainland which is likely desired.
- Try method 1, using just the largest polygon.

Method 3: Attempt to calculate a visual center using external library.

- Convert the polygon to GeoJSON using the GeoJSON module in Bing Maps: https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk/geojsonwritetogeojson
- Pass the geojson geometry into this library to calculate the visual center. https://github.com/mapbox/polylabel